# How to call a function in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to build a simple parse json example.
I took the code from the following link :
http://jsfiddle.net/mjaric/pJ5BR/

```
 <p>    Click <a ng-click="loadPeople()">here</a> to load data.</p>
```

All I want to do is instead of loading the data when clicking a button, I want it to load immediatly. 
What can I use instead of ng-click ? I've tried ng-init but it didn't work.
Any idea?
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can set a init function in your controller then call it int the controller after the init function definition. like below

```
var init = function(){
  //add your init code
  var httpRequest = $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: '/echo/json/',
        data: mockDataForThisTest

    }).success(function(data, status) {
        $scope.people = data;
    });
}

init();
```

And the above sloution is work. OR u can try the ng-init like below

```
<div ng-controller="PeopleCtrl" ng-init="loadPeople()">
```

I think the second is the one u want : )

Comment: the ng-init is what I tried and that's exacly what I needed. I didn't notice I had error cause it couldn't find the JSON and that was the reso

Answer (score 0):

If you want to immediately load the data you have to immediately call the `loadPeople()` function.
E.g. in the **[code you link to](http://jsfiddle.net/mjaric/pJ5BR/)**, you can add the following line at the end of your controller:

```
$scope.loadPeople();
```

---

See, also, this **[short demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mjaric/pJ5BR/)**.